# Calculating total time while certain condition is met Ingres Database

Tags: sql, database, ingres

I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate the total time while a certain condition is met. For example,

| Date | Speed |
| --- | --- |
| 25-jan-2021 15:06:06 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:07:06 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:08:07 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:09:18 | 100.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:10:18 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:11:19 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:12:20 | 150.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:13:20 | 100.000 |
| 25-jan-2021 15:14:20 | 150.000 |

**Date is type ingresdate and Speed is type float**

I need to only calculate the time elapsed while the speed is > 100. Originally I had, `Select MAX(Date) - MIN(Date) AS Difference from table WHERE Speed > 100` However, as you can probably already tell, that only returns the time elapsed between the first date and the last date. The answer I need in this example would be about six minutes if my math is correct. Any help at all would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where speed > 100, not less than, or... do you mean how much time since the speed hits 100 and remains higher to the 150, and before it drops back to 100.  All your values are exactly 100 or 150, no scenario showing what you want if it dips.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: If you're using a version of Ingres recent enough to include it, take a look at the LAG windowing function. This can be used to provide time and speed for the previous row as well as the current row, which could help with calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to divide the ENTIRE table into segments and sum only the necessary (> 100) segments.

In PostgreSQL this one will work:

```
    with t as (select '25-jan-2021 15:06:06'::timestamp as Date,
                      '150.000'::float as Speed
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:07:06','150.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:08:07','150.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:09:18','100.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:10:18','150.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:11:19','150.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:12:20','150.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:13:20','100.000'
               union
               select '25-jan-2021 15:14:20','150.000'
               )
select
    sum(case when z1.Speed > 100 then (z1.Date - z2.Date)::interval end ) as duration_1,
    sum(case when z1.Speed > 100 then extract(epoch from (z1.Date - z2.Date)) end) as duration_in_sec,
    sum(case when z1.Speed > 100 then extract(epoch from (z1.Date - z2.Date)) end)/60 as duration_in_min_part
from (select t.Date,
             t.Speed,
             row_number() OVER (order by t.Date) as rnum
      from t) z1
inner join (select t.Date,
             t.Speed,
             row_number() OVER (order by t.Date) as rnum
      from t) z2
on z1.rnum + 1 = z2.rnum;
```

[output_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWSxQ.png)